# Core Data 'modified' timestamp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I'm trying to set up an automatic 'modified' timestamp with my Core Data object graph. I've got it working within each model with the following code:

```
- (void)willSave
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:date forKey:@"modified"];
    [super willSave];
}
```

However, I'd like this modified date to be able to bubble up the object graph, changing the modified date for each parent object in turn.

So if I have: Grandparent--(hasMany)-->>Parent--(hasMany)-->>Child and I change a property of Child, the Parent and Grandparent modified timestamps should all update to the same value.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may register for the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notification. In it's userInfo, you get a list of updated, deleted, and inserted managed objects.

Next step would be to iterate over the inserted and updated objects, then introspect objects (isKindOfClass, respondsToSelector, ...) and assign a timestamp on picked objects.

Best,

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you traversed up the parent objects to update the timestamps?